# How do I read or modify java controls on user interface from a couple of threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, controls

I'll write a summary of the code and then I'll explain.

I have a **STARTER** button which start a procedure and a progress monitor for it

```
// from a button
actionPerformed()
    // enable procedure control buttons pause and cancel at this point
    SomeProcedure ProcTh = new SomeProcedure(aTable)
    ProcTh.Start();
    ProcessLog LogTh = new ProcessLog(aTable, aProgressBar)
    LogTh.Start();
    // inside try catch:
    ProcTh.join();
    LogTh.join();
```

This is a summary of called procedure thread:

```
class SomeProcedure extends Thread
    JTable aTable = null;
    // the executable part
    public void run()
        for (int i=0;i<aTable.getRowCount();i++)
            // process data in a row
            while (Paused &&! Canceled)
                wait(); // inside a try catch
            if (Canceled)
                i=aTable.getRowCount()-1; // maybe a break is better??
    // the constructor part initializes things
    public SomeProcedure (JTable T)
        aTable = T;
```

This is a summary of called monitor thread:

```
class ProcessLog extends Thread
    JTable aTable = null;
    JProgressBar aBar = null;
    // the executable part
    public void run()
        while (sofarlong<totallong)
            aBar.setValue((int)(sofarlong/totallong));
            // also update values in aTable
    // the constructor part
        public ProgressLog (JTable T, JProgressBar B)
            aTable = T;
            aBar = B;
```

I've got no compiling ERR, but when I click the **STARTER** it hangs pressed and the buttons for pause and cancel won't enable. I'm probably doing something wrong. Is this the best way to **update GUI controls** from threads in java? Is this the best way to **show progress** made by another thread?
I've noticed I can't access GUI controls from the **run** inside threads, that's why I passed them on creating the threads.

SomeProcedure writes on **SoFarLong** while it's processing table rown and ProcessLog will only read it. SoFarLong it's a common variable at GUI level, same as SomeProcedure and ProcessLog, say it's called GUI.java ---

As always, any help or orientation is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Thread.join()` will block until the thread is finished. By calling that within your button handler, your button handler doesn't return until the process is finished.